# Why cygnus crashes when using ngsiv2 in orion?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

Recently I start working with NGSIV2 but cygnus start crashing.
May I have something not cofigurated right? With the v1 works flawless.

My startup trace with the error is in here: http://pastebin.com/nP2am8GW

The error said: Error appending event to channel. Channel might be full. Consider increasing the channel capacity or make sure the sinks perform faster.

```
time=2016-05-09T05:58:28.866CDT | lvl=WARN | trans=1462791485-602-0000000000 | srv=papel-club | subsrv=events | function=intercept | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor[135] : No context responses within the notified entity, nothing is done
time=2016-05-09T05:58:28.867CDT | lvl=WARN | trans=1462791485-602-0000000000 | srv=papel-club | subsrv=events | function=doPost | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource$FlumeHTTPServlet[203] : Error appending event to channel. Channel might be full. Consider increasing the channel capacity or make sure the sinks perform faster.
org.apache.flume.ChannelException: Unable to put batch on required channel: org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: ckan-channel}
    at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.processEventBatch(ChannelProcessor.java:200)
    at org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource$FlumeHTTPServlet.doPost(HTTPSource.java:201)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: put() called with null event!
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:88)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.put(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:89)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicChannelSemantics.put(BasicChannelSemantics.java:80)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.processEventBatch(ChannelProcessor.java:189)
    ... 16 more
```

As error said i increase the channel memory. Here is my agent config:

```
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = ckan-sink
cygnusagent.channels = ckan-channel

cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = ckan-channel
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = papel-club
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = /events
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 5
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules_day.conf

cygnusagent.channels.ckan-channel.type = memory
cygnusagent.channels.ckan-channel.capacity = 100000
cygnusagent.channels.ckan-channel.transactionCapacity = 100000

# ============================================
# OrionCKANSink configuration
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.channel = ckan-channel

# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionCKANSink

# true if the grouping feature is enabled for this sink, false otherwise
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.enable_grouping = true

# true if lower case is wanted to forced in all the element names, false otherwise
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.enable_lowercase = false

# the CKAN API key to use
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.api_key = xxxx

# the FQDN/IP address for the CKAN API endpoint
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.ckan_host = ckan-demo.ckan.io

# the port for the CKAN API endpoint
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.ckan_port = 80

# Orion URL used to compose the resource URL with the convenience operation URL to query it
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.orion_url = http://localhost:1026

# how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column)
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.attr_persistence = column

# enable SSL for secure Http transportation; 'true' or 'false'
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.ssl = false

# number of notifications to be included within a processing batch
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_size = 100

# timeout for batch accumulation
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_timeout = 60

# number of retries upon persistence error
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_ttl = 10
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could be this issue https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/issues/953?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being, NGSIv2 is not supported in Cygnus. It is [expected to be implemented](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/issues/953), but it has not been scheduled yet.

**EDIT:** note also that you can use NGSIv2 to create/update entities at Orion and have notifications in NGSIv1 if you:

- Create the subscription using NGSIv1 operations
- Create the subscription using NGSIv2 operations with `attrsFormat` equal to `legacy`. Have a look to more detailed information [here](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/v1_v2_coexistence/index.html#ngsiv1-notification-with-ngsiv2-subscriptions).