# How to make an Orion NGSIv2 subscription that notifies cygnus in NGSIv1?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

**EDIT 2**

```
curl  --include \
      --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      --request POST \
      --data-binary '{
                       "description": "Day subscription",
                       "subject": {
                         "entities": [
                           {
                             "idPattern": "es-leon-.*",
                             "type": "Event"
                           }
                         ],
                         "condition": {
                           "attrs": [
                              "Title",
                              "dFlag"
                           ],
                           "expression": {
                             "q": "dFlag>0"
                           }
                         }
                       },
                       "notification": {
                         "http": {
                             "url" : "http://localhost:5050/notify"
                         },
                         "attrs": [
                           "Title",
                           "dFlag"
                         ],
                         "attrsFormat":"legacy"
                       }
                     }' \
      'http://localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions'
```

In Orion the subscription register ok (thanks for the tips in the comments) but I'm having the same issue as said in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114255/why-cygnus-crashes-when-using-ngsiv2-in-orion) even though I use `"attrsFormat":"legacy"`
I'm making something wrong? why orion is not using ngsiv1 to send the notification to cygnus?

[The cygnus error trace.](http://pastebin.com/3dW54QEe)

Cygnus shows orion is responding this:

```
{
    "subscriptionId": "574315e77775f31b8d3da719",
    "data": [{
        "id": "es-leon-0",
        "type": "Event",
        "Title": {
            "type": "none",
            "value": "pepe",
            "metadata": {}
        },
        "dFlag": {
            "type": "text",
            "value": "1",
            "metadata": {}
        }
    }]
}
```

When it has to respond the lines below to be in ngsiv1:

```
{
    "subscriptionId": "5743178d7775f31b8d3da71a",
    "originator": "localhost",
    "contextResponses": [{
        "contextElement": {
            "type": "Event",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "es-leon-0",
            "attributes": [{
                "name": "Title",
                "type": "text",
                "value": "pep"
            }, {
                "name": "dFlag",
                "type": "text",
                "value": "1"
            }]
        },
        "statusCode": {
            "code": "200",
            "reasonPhrase": "OK"
        }
    }]
}
```

---

**Original Question**

As said in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114255/why-cygnus-crashes-when-using-ngsiv2-in-orion) :

> EDIT: note also that you can use NGSIv2 to create/update entities at
>   Orion and have notifications in NGSIv1 if you:
>
> Create the subscription using NGSIv1 operations
>
> Create the subscription using NGSIv2 operations with attrsFormat equal to legacy.
>   Have a look to more detailed information [here](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/v1_v2_coexistence/index.html#ngsiv1-notification-with-ngsiv2-subscriptions).

So I made up this subscription:

```
curl  --include \
      --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      --request POST \
      --data-binary '{
                       "description": "Day subscription",
                       "subject": {
                         "entities": [
                           {
                             "idPattern": "es-leon-.*",
                             "type": "Event"
                           }
                         ],
                         "condition": {
                           "attributes": [
                              "Title",
                              "dFlag"
                           ],
                           "expression": {
                             "q": "dFlag > 0"
                           }
                         }
                       },
                       "notification": {
                         "callback": "http://localhost:5050/notify",
                         "attributes": [
                           "Title",
                           "dFlag"
                         ]
                       }
                     }' \
      'http://localhost:1026/v1/subscriptions'
```

but orion don't let me register it throwing this error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 67
Content-Type: application/json
Fiware-Correlator: 2ecdfc74-1c2f-11e6-82d7-000d3a23bf27
Date: Tue, 17 May 2016 12:59:25 GMT

{"error":"BadRequest","description":"no condition attrs specified"}
```

Is this the way to use legacy attributes so it can work with cygnus with NGSIv2?
Thanks for the help.

**EDIT 1:**

Following the answer the subscription should be like this: Right?

```
curl  --include \
      --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      --request POST \
      --data-binary '{
                       "description": "Day subscription",
                       "subject": {
                         "entities": [
                           {
                             "idPattern": "es-leon-.*",
                             "type": "Event"
                           }
                         ],
                         "condition": {
                           "attributes": [
                              "Title",
                              "dFlag"
                           ],
                           "expression": {
                             "q": "dFlag > 0"
                           }
                         }
                       },
                       "notification": {
                         "http": {
                             "url" : "http://localhost:5050/notify"
                         },
                         "attributes": [
                           "Title",
                           "dFlag"
                         ],
                         "attrsFormat":"legacy"
                       }
                     }' \
      'http://localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions'
```

But I'm still getting an error:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 67
Content-Type: application/json
Fiware-Correlator: 60a0a1d2-1ddf-11e6-8bd6-000d3a23bf27
Date: Thu, 19 May 2016 16:33:11 GMT

{"error":"BadRequest","description":"no condition attrs specified"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `attrs` instead of `attributes` (both in `subject.conditions` and in `notification`).

In addition, note that `callback` is no longer used. You have to use:

```
"notification": {
  "http": {
    "url": "http://localhost:5050/notify"
  },
  ..
}
```

In addition, if you want notifications to use NGSIv1 format you should include `attrsFormat` field with value `legacy` in `notification` as described in [the documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/v1_v2_coexistence/index.html#ngsiv1-notification-with-ngsiv2-subscriptions).

Finally, note that the rigth operation URL is `/v2/subscriptions`, not `/v1/subscriptions` as shown in your example.

**EDIT 1:** considering the new payload in EDIT 1 section in the question, note that:

- You should use `attrs` inside `condition`, not `attributes` (the error message is complaining about that)
- You should use `attrs` inside `notification`, not `attributes`
- You should use `"q": "dFlag>0"` (i.e. no whitespaces in the query string). Look to the example in the [NGSIv2 specification](http://fiware.github.io/specifications/ngsiv2/latest/):

Eg:

```
"expression": {
  "q": "temperature>40"
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Orion versions previous to 1.2 use `attrsFormat` outside `notification` field. Thus, if you are using Orion 1.1, try to use `"attrsFormat": "legacy"` as first level field in the subscription payload JSON.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but I just try and have no luck, take a look at my edit maybe you will find what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I have added a "EDIT 1" section to my post, to answer that part.

Comment: Edit 2 made in the question, subscription now is registered but orion is responding in the new ngsi format. What did I made wrong in the subscription?

Comment: Please see Edit 2 fragment in my answer. Note that Orion 1.2 has not been yet released (it will be released by the end of May or early June) but I'm answering in advance so the answer may survive the past of time :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.